# How do I make my Map View zoom to the previous frame after a segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, segue

When the user first loads the map, the map zooms in on the current user's location. I have various annotations on my map in one view controller. When users press the callout of the annotation, it takes them to a new view with a segue. Then the user can press "Done" in the new view, and it takes them back to the first map. However, when the user comes back to the first view controller, the map zooms to the current location again, instead of zooming back to the previous frame that he/she had right before pressing the callout.

This is my code to track in the first View. It is called every time one segues back from the second view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
self.mapView.delegate = self;
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
.......
}
```

Comment: How and where do you zoom in on the user location initially? I assume you are doing it wrongly so it's invoked again when you come back.

Comment: Hey, I updated my question with the code I use.